# How to create sh script which will run SQL file on CentOS without sqlplus lib

Tags: sql, bash, oracle, sh, centos7

I'd need to create a sh script, which will connect to Oracle DB and then execute a SQL file.
The problem is that sqlplus is not installed on that Cent-OS machine and most probably it won't be installed either.
Is there a way how to do this?

Comment: There is nothing native to the OS that is going to know how to connect to oracle and process sql statements. You must install an oracle client, including sqlplus. Why do you say it won't be installed?

Comment: @EdStevens, let's say the machine is not under our management anymore. But asking whether oracle client is installed there is worthy.

Comment: One general way, though I'm guessing the setup issues may not suit you, is to have Oracle's REST service 'ORDS' installed on the DB, and then execute each statement via a REST call.  Other than that, you have to install some kind of client stack, as others have mentioned.  Instant Client is probably the smallest, though you could use JDBC if you have Java installed.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily install Oracle Instant Client including sqlplus executable ("Free to download, deploy and distribute").

See 
https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/linux-x86-64-downloads.html

Answer (score 0):

**If** some **java** version **is installed** on the server, you can create a simple class that will connect to oracle DB via JDBC, load the sql script and execute it.

1. Create and compile java class
2. Upload class file, sql script + oracle_driver (jar file) (https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/jdbcdriver-ucp-downloads.html)
3. Execute the java program

Answer (score 0):

You can’t. You need to install oracle client which include sqlplus or sqlloader.
Or you can use Python and library Cx_Oracle, but you still need sqlclient to connect to database.
If you don’t want to install oracle client, you can use external table to load data to database or some etl tool.